# What will happen to my Pecan tassies if I use too much butter?

Tags: baking, pecan

When I was making Pecan tassies, I read the recipe wrong and put a stick of butter in for the filling instead of 2 tablespoons. There are two eggs, 1 1/2 cups brown sugar, vanilla extract. Will it turn out with that much butter?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming your stick of butter is 8 tablespoons, right?  So you used four times as much butter as the recipe calls for, which is probably enough to make it into a buttery mess.

I think your two best options are: 1) increase all other ingredients by the same amount and make a lot of tassies, or 2) start over.

Comment: Agreed and it's probably cheaper to start over. 2x ingredients vs 4x ingredients. Pecans are expensive.

Comment: If you start over, the ingredients might make something else - a filling for baked rolls or with flour the base of some baked goods.